# Error executing the presentViewController command

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

I am sure I am just missing one step but I am at a loss to figure out what. I am trying to write a function I can call repeatedly to error check several fields. When a required field is empty, the function will be called to remind the user and not allow him/her to proceed.  I wrote the code to error trap the first field but then tried to make it a function I call for the rest. This is just for testing so I know the code works at least for one field (which it does).

When I run and the first field is empty, I get the error message and behavior I expect. When I run and the first field has data but the second field does not, I get no error message (no activity at all, actually).

I have tried to add `self.presentViewController(dataErrorAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)` in the function but it errors saying:

> cannot invoke 'presentViewContoller' with an argument list of type'((String, error: String) -> (), animated: Bool, completion: nil)

I don't know what my options are for calling the `presentViewController` command. Here is the relevant code. Thank you for your assistance.

```
var missingDataError = ""

func dataErrorAlert(title:String, error:String) {
    var dataMissingAlert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: missingDataError, preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
    dataMissingAlert.addAction((UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Cancel, handler: nil)))
    self.presentViewController(dataErrorAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

@IBAction func next(sender: AnyObject) {
    if enterPersonnelName.text == "" {
       let dataErrorAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Oops", message: "The Name field is empty and is required information.", preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
        var cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Cancel, handler: nil)
        dataErrorAlert.addAction(cancelAction)
        self.presentViewController(dataErrorAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        blankData = 1
    } else { if enterDrugID.text == "" {
            self.missingDataError = "The Drug ID field is empty and is required."
            self.dataErrorAlert("Ooops", error: missingDataError)
            blankData = 1
    } else { if enterPackageNumber.text == "" {
            self.missingDataError = "The Package Number field is empty and is required."
            self.dataErrorAlert("Ooops", error: missingDataError)
            blankData = 1
            }
    }
    }
        if blankData != 1 {
            //add code to pass data to next veiw controller
            //self.appIsWorking
            performSegueWithIdentifier("goToDispenseScreenThree", sender: self)
        }
    blankData = 0
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that `dataErrorAlert` is a `function`, I am guessing you want to display `dataMissingAlert` that is an `UIAlertController`, try this:

```
self.presentViewController(dataMissingAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

You probably should try to rename your alert or your `function` as seems you have both with the name `dataErrorAlert`, I normally would user `dataErrorAlertController`.
I hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you. That was so simple and yet I have been going round and round with it all afternoon. I took your advice on the function name of `dataErrorAlertController`. Naming my variables and functions is one (of many) things I need to get better at. In my defense, in the class I took on Swift programming, the instructor was not good at variable and function naming. He was trying to go fast but it was not helpful to me.

Comment: It happens with all of us :)  try to be the most descriptive as possible, xcode helps you with the autocomplete anyway :) I am hoping xcode7 will have the refractory for swift working what will make this renaming process much easier as well. Good lucky with your app!